# PHP type check for associative array index isn't string, like it should be

Tags: php, type-conversion, associative-array

I'm running into an issue here.

```
$arr = array ('1' => 'one');
var_dump(current(array_keys($arr)));
   // prints: int(1)
   // should print: string(1) "1"
```

I am trying to create an associative array, but PHP is converting my strings into integers on me.

I am generating markup for a series of <input type="radio"> buttons, and applying the checked attribute to the one whose value matches that in the POST request, e.g.

```
$selected = isset($_POST[$this->name]) ? $_POST[$this->name] : null;
foreach ($this->options as $value => $label) {
   $html .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"{$this->name}\" value=\"$value\"".
            ($_POST[$this->name] === $value ? ' checked' : '').'>';
}
```

I could just use two equal signs and not type-compare; however, if the array is:

```
$this->options = array (
   '0' => 'No',
   '1' => 'Yes'
);
```

it would select the 0 option, even if the the POST value isn't set. However, it shouldn't select ANY radio button, because none of them have the value of null.

**EDIT:** Just found this: "Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer." in the PHP Manual. Think there'd be anyway to circumvent that?

Comment: also you could type cast to string like `(string)$integer`

Comment: php is loosely typed, its not going to matter if its a string\int

Comment: @Twisted1919: Duh! Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of that, I was approaching the problem wrong.

Comment: @Dagon: PHP's loose typing drives me nuts actually, I don't want values like false, null, and 0 to be equivalent when they mean very different things.

Comment: then stop using php, ruby and python are popular

Comment: I don't get to choose which language I program in, only one gets me my paycheck....

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is, as @Twisted1919 said, to typecast in the check.

```
$selected = isset($_POST[$this->name]) ? $_POST[$this->name] : null;
foreach ($this->options as $value => $label) {
   $html .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"{$this->name}\" value=\"$value\"".
            ($selected === (string) $value ? ' checked' : '').'>';
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
A key may be either an integer or a string. If a key is the standard representation
of an integer, it will be interpreted as such (i.e. "8" will be interpreted as 8, 
while "08" will be interpreted as "08").
```

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that. I was looking for an alternative solution.